# Why did the property in Objective-C not remain set?

Tags: objective-c

At this point in the class username and token are not null according to the debugger

```
[storage getUserData];
current.token = storage.token;
current.username = storage.username;
```

In `getUserData` they are also not null

```
-(void) getUserData
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *token1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"token"];
    NSString *username1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];
    if (token1 && username1)
    {
        self.token = token1;
        self.username = username1;
    }
}
```

But if the properties token and username are accessed from another class after calling  getUserData they are both null. I don't know why.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. Can you post the whole code or at least post and explain the relevant parts.

Comment: How do you retain `storage`? Is it a singleton?

Comment: you have not allocated storage class

Comment: Do you use a custom setter for the username? As W.K.S. said, there isn't enough info now to answer.

Comment: please edit your question. Its hard to understand what you are trying to explain.

Answer (score -3):

```
    in storage.h

//Declaring propert for varriable
    @property (nonatomic , retain)NSString* token;
    @property (nonatomic , retain)NSString* username;

    in storage.m

#pragma mark- Declaring singleton object
    + (id)sharedManager {
        static storage *sharedStorage = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedStorage = [[self alloc] init];
        });
        return sharedStorage;
    }


    -(void) getUserData
    {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *token1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"token"];
        NSString *username1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];
        if (token1 && username1)
        {
            self.token = token1;
            self.username = username1;
        }
    }

    in current.m
//it will get user data and set token and username
    [[storage sharedManager]getUserData];
    current.token = storage.token;
    current.username = storage.username;
```

you have not allocated your storage class that's why variable do not get set.

Comment: This lacks any explanation of what you have done to help. Please use the edit button and add some explanation because at present this is a poor answer -1 for lack of explanation.

Comment: It's clear (especially after the question has been edited) that `storage` initialization code has just been skipped. It's not the cause of the problem. And why are you suggesting this strange `sharedManager`? It has nothing to do with the question.